# TCPDF and Graidle

Tags: php, charts, tcpdf

I am using Graidle to generate a pie chart on the fly like given below:

```
<iframe src=" profile_second_2.php?age=43&inflation=2&n=45454" width="450" height="450" style="border:0px; padding-left:50px; border:1px solid #fff;"> </iframe>
```

`profile_second_2.php` is the file that is generating pie chart and its working fine for website.

Pie chart is displayed as an image on website.

I want this pie chart to be displayed in pdf using TCPDF while pdf and pie chart both are getting generated obvious pie chart is getting generated first.

How can I do it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You must generate a PNG file using the Graidle's function **carry2file** in **profile_second_2.php**.
Something like:

```
$chart->carry2file("app/files/tmp/", 'chartImage');
```

After that, you can insert the image on the TCPDF document using the function **image**:

```
$pdf->Image('app/files/tmp/chartImage.png', 10, 10, 180, 110, 'PNG');
```

The parameters of Image function are: string file, float x, float y, float width, float height, string type.